# How to get an equation to take in a list of points

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics, vector

I am trying to solve and plot a vector which is equal to (xi,yi)+gradientf(xi,yi). I solve for the gradient by finding the derivative. I am struggling with how to write/get the function to take in my list of "pnts1" one at a time into the equation listed above. I guess my main problem is getting mathematica to pick up each point as an xi,yi value.

```
f[x_, y_] = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
h = D[x + x/(x^2 + y^2), x];
w = D[x + x/(x^2 + y^2), y]
gradientf = (1 - (2 x^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 1/(x^2 + y^2), -((
2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)^2));
pnts1 = {{-1.8, 0.2}, {-1.8, 0.4}, {-1.8, 0.6}, {-1.8, 0.8}, {-1.8, 
1.}, {-1.8, 1.2}, {-1.8, 1.4}, {-1.8, 1.6}, {-1.8, 1.8}, {-1.8, 
2.}, {-1.6, 0.2}, {-1.6, 0.4}, {-1.6, 0.6}, {-1.6, 0.8}, {-1.6, 
1.}, {-1.6, 1.2}, {-1.6, 1.4}, {-1.6, 1.6}, {-1.6, 1.8}, {-1.6, 
2.}, {-1.4, 0.2}, {-1.4, 0.4}, {-1.4, 0.6}, {-1.4, 0.8}, {-1.4, 
1.}, {-1.4, 1.2}, {-1.4, 1.4}, {-1.4, 1.6}, {-1.4, 1.8}, {-1.4, 
2.}, {-1.2, 0.2}, {-1.2, 0.4}, {-1.2, 0.6}, {-1.2, 0.8}, {-1.2, 
1.}, {-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.4}, {-1.2, 1.6}, {-1.2, 1.8}, {-1.2, 
2.}, {-1., 0.2}, {-1., 0.4}, {-1., 0.6}, {-1., 0.8}, {-1., 
1.}, {-1., 1.2}, {-1., 1.4}, {-1., 1.6}, {-1., 1.8}, {-1., 
2.}, {-0.8, 0.6}, {-0.8, 0.8}, {-0.8, 1.}, {-0.8, 1.2}, {-0.8, 
1.4}, {-0.8, 1.6}, {-0.8, 1.8}, {-0.8, 2.}, {-0.6, 0.8}, {-0.6, 
1.}, {-0.6, 1.2}, {-0.6, 1.4}, {-0.6, 1.6}, {-0.6, 1.8}, {-0.6, 
2.}, {-0.4, 1.}, {-0.4, 1.2}, {-0.4, 1.4}, {-0.4, 1.6}, {-0.4, 
1.8}, {-0.4, 2.}, {-0.2, 1.}, {-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.4}, {-0.2, 
1.6}, {-0.2, 1.8}, {-0.2, 2.}, {0., 1.}, {0., 1.2}, {0., 1.4}, {0.,
1.6}, {0., 1.8}, {0., 2.}, {0.2, 1.}, {0.2, 1.2}, {0.2, 
1.4}, {0.2, 1.6}, {0.2, 1.8}, {0.2, 2.}, {0.4, 1.}, {0.4, 
1.2}, {0.4, 1.4}, {0.4, 1.6}, {0.4, 1.8}, {0.4, 2.}, {0.6, 
0.8}, {0.6, 1.}, {0.6, 1.2}, {0.6, 1.4}, {0.6, 1.6}, {0.6, 
1.8}, {0.6, 2.}, {0.8, 0.6}, {0.8, 0.8}, {0.8, 1.}, {0.8, 
1.2}, {0.8, 1.4}, {0.8, 1.6}, {0.8, 1.8}, {0.8, 2.}, {1., 
0.2}, {1., 0.4}, {1., 0.6}, {1., 0.8}, {1., 1.}, {1., 1.2}, {1., 
1.4}, {1., 1.6}, {1., 1.8}, {1., 2.}, {1.2, 0.2}, {1.2, 0.4}, {1.2,
0.6}, {1.2, 0.8}, {1.2, 1.}, {1.2, 1.2}, {1.2, 1.4}, {1.2, 
1.6}, {1.2, 1.8}, {1.2, 2.}, {1.4, 0.2}, {1.4, 0.4}, {1.4, 
0.6}, {1.4, 0.8}, {1.4, 1.}, {1.4, 1.2}, {1.4, 1.4}, {1.4, 
1.6}, {1.4, 1.8}, {1.4, 2.}, {1.6, 0.2}, {1.6, 0.4}, {1.6, 
0.6}, {1.6, 0.8}, {1.6, 1.}, {1.6, 1.2}, {1.6, 1.4}, {1.6, 
1.6}, {1.6, 1.8}, {1.6, 2.}, {1.8, 0.2}, {1.8, 0.4}, {1.8, 
0.6}, {1.8, 0.8}, {1.8, 1.}, {1.8, 1.2}, {1.8, 1.4}, {1.8, 
1.6}, {1.8, 1.8}, {1.8, 2.}, {2., 0.2}, {2., 0.4}, {2., 0.6}, {2., 
0.8}, {2., 1.}, {2., 1.2}, {2., 1.4}, {2., 1.6}, {2., 1.8}, {2., 
2.}}
vector = (x, y) + gradientf;
```

Comment: You do not appear to understand how to use the different types of brackets. See [`The Four Kinds of Bracketing in the Wolfram Language`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheFourKindsOfBracketingInTheWolframLanguage.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = x + x/(x^2 + y^2);
gradientf[x_, y_] = D[f[x, y], {{x, y}}]
```

> `{1 - (2 x^2)/(x^2 + y^2)^2 + 1/(x^2 + y^2), -((2 x y)/(x^2 + y^2)^2)}`

Applying this to your points:

```
vector = pnts1 + gradientf @@@ pnts1
```